# How to loop through a folder to encrypt/decrypt files using AES in python and delete original unencrypted files in that folder?

Tags: python, encryption, aes, rsa

I am new to python and learning security and I am testing the below code on my kali VirtualBox machine. I would like to encrypt all files in a given directory(/home/kali/Desktop/files) by using a recursive function and giving them the ending format (.h3ckeD). is there such a way to achieve this?

```
 from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
 from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import rsa
 from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
 from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
 from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding

private_key = rsa.generate_private_key(
   public_exponent=65537,
   key_size=2048,
   backend=default_backend()
   )
public_key = private_key.public_key()

# Storing the keys

pem = private_key.private_bytes(
     encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
     format=serialization.PrivateFormat.PKCS8,
     encryption_algorithm=serialization.NoEncryption()
)

with open('private_key.pem', 'wb') as f:
f.write(pem)

pem = public_key.public_bytes(
    encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
    format=serialization.PublicFormat.SubjectPublicKeyInfo
)

  # Encrypting and decrypting


f = open('test.txt', 'rb')
    message = f.read()
 f.close()
 encrypted = public_key.encrypt(
 message,
  padding.OAEP(
     mgf=padding.MGF1(algorithm=hashes.SHA256()),
     algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
     label=None
    )
  )

 original_message = private_key.decrypt(
     encrypted,
     padding.OAEP(
     mgf=padding.MGF1(algorithm=hashes.SHA256()),
     algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
    label=None
   )
  )

   with open('rsa.decrypted.txt', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(original_message)
```

Comment: What happened when you ran that code?

Comment: It only encrypts 1 file (test.text) in the base directory. I want it to recursively loop through all the files in a directory and encrypt every file

Comment: Unfortunately you have syntax errors (indentation) in the code you've shown. Once you've corrected that you'll probably find it easier to implement the full use-case

Comment: Why are you using RSA in code when you want to encrypt files using AES?